# Flex BlazeDS dynamic configuration

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, blazeds, flex-mobile

i'm here with a new question - this time more general; hope most of you have experienced this.

So than I configured my flex mobile project so that it requires to update server URL adresses each time server ip or port is changed:
[image]

But in my case my flex mobile project will run in different hospitals that so it will need more updates each time server address is changed - and also in cases when hospital servers is restricted to outside its just impossible do that from my remote computer. As I need to update remote object classes as well:
[image]

So, the above method seems not very suitable for my case. How can I configure my project so that I could change server url by changing the one on runtime using textareas etc. to set that as below:

[image]

Briefly speaking I'm talking about externalizing the configuration for AMF channel endpoint url.

Any help will be greatly appreciated !...

Answer (score 1):

You can just build the messaging consumer yourself and specify the correct channel:

```
function initConsumer():void { 
  var channelSet:ChannelSet = new ChannelSet();
  // for streaming
  var myChannel:Channel = new StreamingAMFChannel("streaming-channel", "http://something.com/messagebroker/");
  // for polling
  var myChannel:Channel = new AMFChannel("polling-channel", "http://something.com/messagebroker/");
  myChannel.pollingEnabled = true;

  channelSet.addChannel(myChannel);

  var consumer:Consumer = new Consumer();
  consumer.channelSet = channelSet;
  consumer.destination = "NASDAQ"; 
  consumer.selector = "operation IN ('Bid','Ask')";
  consumer.addEventListener(MessageEvent.MESSAGE, messageHandler); 
  consumer.subscribe(); 
} 

function messageHandler(event:MessageEvent):void { 
  var msg:IMessage = event.message; 
  var info:Object = msg.body; 
  trace("-App recieved message: " + msg.toString()); 
}
```